# Detect when all options of a select have changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

Is there a way to detect when an attribute of all options within a select have changed?
E.g.

```
<select id="languages">
    <option value="en">English<option>
    <option value="fr">French<option>
    <option value="de">German<option>
    ...
</select>
```

and a third party plugin will add(first time) or change(second + time) lang attribute, so it will become:

```
<select id="languages">
    <option value="en" lang="fr">Anglais<option>
    <option value="fr" lang="fr">Français<option>
    <option value="de" lang="fr">Allemand<option>
    ...
</select>
```

So I would like to watch/detect when all options's attribute have changed, so I can call my functions. I think mutationobserver can be the way, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Would that not be `<option value="en" lang="fr">Anglais<option><option value="fr" lang="fr">Français<option><option value="de" lang="fr">Allemand<option>` ?

Comment: Yes, it would be, but the only thing I can check are the lang attribute, so it's not really important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, if somebody needs it in the future:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log('Do your thing');
    });
});

var observerConfig = { 
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['lang'],
    subtree: true
};

var target = document.querySelector('.languages');

observer.observe(target, observerConfig);
```